# Salesforce required to store server certificate

Tags: authentication, ssl, api-client-certificate

Do i need to upload server certificate in Salesforce to trust the server while connecting in 2 way ssl?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using mutual authentication/2-way SSL, Salesforce.com can present a self-signed certificate to the target host.

Please check below links it will useful to you:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000007225&type=1

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009B2uIAE

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_keys_uploading_signed_cert.htm&type=0

Comment: Welcome @DildarHussain

Comment: Hi Annappa,
i habe posted one more questions here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166633/self-singed-certificate-for-mutual-tls

could you please check and let me know if you can answer the same.