# Self Singed Certificate for Mutual TLS

Tags: rest-api, authentication, certificates, authorization, api-client-certificate

I need to expose an rest api to an external system, and wanted to allow authentication only through certificate. So as per the salesforce mutual tls feature can we use self signed certificate generated in salesforce and share the same with external system to rest callout?

Please help me, i am little confused that to setup this?

Is it also possible to use Mutual authentication for REST API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutual Authentication  Allows client and server to identify and authenticate each other by using certificates.
check below links:

Ref: http://www.aboveandbeyondcloud.com/mutual-authentification-salesforce/
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454355/security-of-rest-authentication-schemes

How to set uo mutual authentication certificate.Please check below link.It will useful to you
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_keys_uploading_mutual_auth_cert.htm&type=0

*****Please visit below links It will help you:*****
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134079/tls-mutual-authentication-with-self-signed-client-certificate

https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/ka0370000005Q6VAAU/Trusting-an-SSL-Certificate-on-a-Client-Machine

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL

Comment: i already visited last link but did not find anything like self signed certificate is supported by mutual tls. is it required only one certificate? how a client can trust the server?

Comment: its really cool, but new question in my mind like can we use self created CA by openssl toolkit, will it work?